# how to convert wordpress query to pdo query

Tags: php

how to convert this query which works under wordpress, to use it on another site in php

```
  global $wpdb;
        $ID_CATEGORY = 10; 
        $query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT {$wpdb->prefix}users.ID, {$wpdb->prefix}users.display_name as user_nicename, COUNT(*) as count 
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts, {$wpdb->prefix}users, {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships 
        WHERE {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_type='post' 
        AND {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_status='publish' 
        AND {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_author = {$wpdb->prefix}users.ID 
        AND {$wpdb->prefix}posts.ID = {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships.object_id 
        AND {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = %d
        GROUP BY post_author ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 5 ;", $ID_CATEGORY);
        $results = $wpdb->get_results($query, OBJECT);
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want the pure sql code? if thats the case, do `echo $query;`

Comment: Thank you for the answer .
For now this query works on my wordpress site. But I would like to convert it so that it can work on my other site in php

Comment: If the other site is wordpress and has that exact DB layout it will work, if its different,without knowing how your DB is structured it would be imposible to tell.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
So I have two sites, the first in wordpress with a database and the second with php but without a database. I want to display the result of this query on the one in php

Comment: You could create a rest API endpoint in the wordpres site, that will prepare all the data you want to display, and in the php site use XHR request, or a php curl request to get the data from that endpoint.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
how to achieve this?

Comment: To create a custom rest API endpoint see [Adding Custom Endpoints](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/), this is the guide I used to create my own api endpoints in multiple sites, the official wordpress quide, and a good one =], after you created the endpoint you can use [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) to see how it works, post man also comes with a code option that will create the code that you need, you can copy paste it and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will look at this

Comment: @Buttered_Toast can you post your answer as an answer rather than a comment?

Answer (score 0):

I just found my answer

```
"SELECT post_title ,post_date, display_name ,wp_users.ID, wp_users.display_name as user_nicename, COUNT(*) as count 
        FROM wp_posts, wp_users, wp_term_relationships 
        WHERE wp_posts.post_type='post' 
        AND wp_posts.post_status='publish' 
        AND wp_posts.post_author = wp_users.ID 
        AND wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id 
        AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = '10'
        GROUP BY post_author ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 5 ;"
```